# SoundCloud, download or stream file via api

Tags: audio, soundcloud

I try to use download_url to get file from soundcloud.

I either get 'redirected' or '401 unauthorized', how can I download/stream it to client side?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting a 401 response, then you should include your `client_id` in the request. It might also be that it's a private sound, in which case, you'd also have to include the oauth credentials.

The actual success response is a redirect, since the stream files are accessible from a different server, but only with special time-limited access tokens (included in the redirect response). Basically, just follow the redirect and you'll have your stream.

Comment: I'm trying the same, with the same results.

`http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/773150/download&client_id=9bf720..........935998e1ab4f3272`

Leads me to an XML document: 

`<error>401 - Unauthorized</error>`

I own the track, and afaik it is public.

Comment: @LeeGee your URL is incorrectly formed: should be `.../tracks/773150/download?client_id=...` (Note the question mark there)

Answer (score 1):

You are using Wrong Url Structure...
Try This ,Its Working (I tested) :
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/773150/download?client_id={Your ID Here}

You Should Use ? Instead Of & before client_id