# SoundCloud mp3 link and file length for custom podcast feed

Tags: api, audio, mp3, soundcloud, podcast

I have some podcast feeds already up and running in iTunes for my client, but we're thinking of switching their audio from self-hosted to SoundCloud.

Is it possible to use the SoundCloud API to get an mp3 download link and the file length for uploaded tracks?

As an example, here's the enclosure tag from the existing feed for a recent podcast episode:

```
<enclosure url="http://marfapublicradio.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/TLK-130813-Steve-Murdoch-WEB.mp3" length="28077244" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

If I could just insert SoundCloud track data for the url and length attributes I'd be good to go, but after a brief look through at the API documentation I'm not sure whether it can be done.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing this in the related questions list:
[SoundCloud, download or stream file via api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447819/soundcloud-download-or-stream-file-via-api)

led me to further examination of the API docs ( http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks ), where I found that the track properties do include download_url and duration.

So the answer to my question is "yes, it is possible".

Edit as of September 2, 2013:

I was able to make a download link, but only one that initiated a download dialog, and not a URL for an mp3 file that would be appropriate for me feed's enclosure tag.

I tried e-mailing the SoundCloud api support e-mail address, but got no response. I then tried their general support e-mail, and did receive a reply telling me that the answer to my question is NO.

SoundCloud's api does NOT support .mp3 URLs to drop into the enclosure tags in my pre-existing feeds. It was instead suggested that I apply for their podcasting beta, which I will now investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with this myself at the moment. While I am not immediately seeing a direct link to an mp3, I have noticed that the value for the waveform (a random BBC stream used here) can be used to form a working mp3 url:

First get the track info:
`https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/bbc-media-show/nikkei-buys-financial-times&client_id=[yourClientIdHere]`

Notice the waveform url:
`7Yp3d9EHloKg_m.png`

Use that identifier (remove the _m) to form the working stream URL.
http://media.soundcloud.com/stream/7Yp3d9EHloKg.mp3

Forgive my poor text formatting here... I have never used stackoverflow before.